# RC4: Known plaintext key, unknown key derivation

Tags: rc4

I am working with an older piece of software that generates encrypted backups that I'd like to decrypt. I have a plaintext key, a few examples of encrypted data and I'm pretty sure the data is ASCII, but I don't know how they derive the RC4 key from the plaintext key.

How would I go about testing key derivations comprehensively? The space must be relatively small, even if I'm considering all the RC4 key lengths.

Comment: Have you tried just inserting the plaintext key into the RC4 algorithm as is?  It does take variable length (1-256 byte) keys, so that's the obvious way they might have implemented it.

Comment: @poncho The key itself is 237 bytes long - I believe that's too long, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not too long; RC4 can handle keys up to 256 bytes in length

Comment: @poncho, thanks that turned out to be it! It was a raw key.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about testing key derivations comprehensively?

Why don't you start with the most obvious possibility first?  RC4 takes a variable length (1-256 byte) key; perhaps they used the key you present directly as into to the RC4 key setup algorithm?

[From your comments, we already know this answer is the correct one - this is just so that the question has an official answer]